# Aggregate two JMS messages from two different consumers

Tags: jms, mule, aggregate

I have two jms consumers, each in a different flow. I want to use another flow to aggregate the messages of thoe two messages. and also need to keep the correlation Ids as i need to split the payload and send back the messages.

```
    <flow name="integration-consumer-client1" doc:name="integration-consumer-client1">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ" queue="client1.publish"/>
    <logger message="Consumes Client One = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="Client One Correlation = #[message.correlationId]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="client1" doc:name="VM"/>
</flow>
<flow name="integration-consumer-client2" doc:name="integration-consumer-client2">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ" queue="client2.publish"/>
    <logger message="Consumes Client Two = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="Client Two Correlation = #[message.correlationId]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="client2" doc:name="VM"/>
</flow>
<flow name="integration-internetsolutionsFlow1" doc:name="integration-internetsolutionsFlow1">
    <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="client1" doc:name="VM"/>
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="client2" doc:name="VM"/>
    </scatter-gather>
</flow>
```

I tried to use the scatter gather with two inbound VMs but get the following error:

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'vm:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-aggregation-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":threading-profile, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the error is **integration-internetsolutionsFlow1** doesn't have any inbound endpoint ..

What you can do is following :-

Use vm:outbound-endpoint to **same path** from both the flow
   **integration-consumer-client1** and **integration-consumer-client2**

Then in **integration-internetsolutionsFlow1**

```
     <flow name="integration-internetsolutionsFlow1" doc:name="integration-internetsolutionsFlow1">
      <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="Your Path" doc:name="VM" connector-ref="vmConnector" />
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>
<!-- you don't require a setter-getter here -->
    </flow>
```

The path of outbound VM from both the flow  **integration-consumer-client1** and **integration-consumer-client2** should be same..

You no need a scatter-gather here .. since both the flow will disptch the payload to same VM path .. It will be receive by VM inbound endpoint

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have tried the approach. the problem is that the two messages needs to be aggregated. I am sending the combined message to another flow via jms after the aggregation. then that flow edits the data and sends it back to the integration-internetsolutionsFlow1

Comment: Create empty Global Arraylist using MEL and add #[message.payload] into it after VM inbound endpoint...Then get the list value into any flow ... Check this link :- http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/how_to_define_a_global_arraylist_or_map_varible_to_record_data